# How to check to see if audio isn't loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I wrote some audio scraping script that searches for mp3 audio files url links and I loaded its url into my HTML `audio`'s `src`. however, I found out some of mp3 urls are not working properly and therefore the `audio` cannot perform `load()` since the audio file isn't there to work with in the first place. I looked up the `audio\video` html dom reference but I haven't found any useful methods or properties that would return a value if the audio isn't loaded properly.

say I have the following code:

```
var url= $(data).find(".download_button a").attr('href');
$('source').attr("src", url);   
$('#mp3').get(0).load();
$('#mp3').get(0).play();
```

for instance, if the url is like this:http://www.7inchpunk.com/wp-content/upload1/01LetsGetRidOfNewYork.mp3. which is a website that can't be found. I cannot do `if($('#mp3').get(0).load())` because `load()` has no return value. So how do I check to see if an audio file is loaded or not?

Comment: Did you try hooking into the `$(source)` `onerror` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the `onerror` event of the source object:

```
var url = 'http://www.7inchpunk.com/wp-content/upload1/01LetsGetRidOfNewYork.mp3';

$('source').attr("src", url);   
$('#mp3').get(0).load();
$('#mp3').get(0).play();

$('source').on('error', function () {
    console.log('OOPS');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9Lh78e2/